# How to select a same column from a specialized table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE Person(
    IDPerson VARCHAR(10),
    name VARCHAR(50),
    PRIMARY KEY(IDPerson)
);
```

`Person` table is a general table which has these 2 specialization:

```
CREATE TABLE Physician(
    IDPhysician VARCHAR(10),
    specialty VARCHAR(50),
    PRIMARY KEY(IDPhysician),
    FOREIGN KEY(IDPhysician) REFERENCES Person(IDPerson)
);
CREATE TABLE Volunteer(
    IDVolunteer VARCHAR(10),
    IDSupervisor VARCHAR(10),
    skill VARCHAR(30),
    PRIMARY KEY(IDVolunteer),
    FOREIGN KEY(IDVolunteer) REFERENCES Person(IDPerson),
    FOREIGN KEY(IDSupervisor) REFERENCES Physician(IDPhysician)
);
```

I want to select data from physician and volunteer with the name of each person. Is there any possible way to do this?

Let's say I have this example data:

Person:

| IDPerson | Name |
| --- | --- |
| P001 | Andy |
| P002 | Rudy |
| P003 | Budy |
| P004 | Khal |
| P005 | Apho |

Phycisian:

| IDPhysician | specialty |
| --- | --- |
| P004 | heart |
| P005 | brain |

Volunteer:

| IDVolunteer | IDSupervisor | skill |
| --- | --- | --- |
| P001 | P004 | skill1 |
| P002 | P004 | skill2 |
| P003 | P005 | skill2 |

This is what I expect as an output:

```
IDVolunteer | Name | IDSupervisor | Name
------------|------|--------------|--------
P001        | Andy | P004         | Khal 
------------|------|--------------|--------
P002        | Rudy | P004         | Khal 
------------|------|--------------|--------
P003        | Budy | P005         | Apho 
------------|------|--------------|--------
```

Comment: So according to the desired output you do not need a `Phycisian` table at all for this question. Please, show your current code and describe what is wrong with it.

Comment: Yes, turns out I don't need ```Phycisian``` table, but I need to select the name of each person from ```Volunteer``` table. That's the query I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if this works for you.

```
SELECT
    V.IDVolunteer,
    P.name,
    V.IDSupervisor,
    Ph.name,
FROM
    Volunteer V
INNER JOIN Person P
    ON P.IDPerson = V.IDVolunteer
INNER JOIN Person Ph
    ON Ph.IDPerson = V.IDSupervisor;
```

Comment: this worked! Thank you. I didn't know that I can do join operation 2 times.

Comment: @DionisiusPratama You may use the same table as much times as you need (and join on any condition that is a predicate), but have to assign different aliases to them.

Comment: Glad to know that, Well as @astentx said, you can join the tables multiple times as long as your conditions are written in a correct way :)

Comment: okay. Thank you all for the insights you have given.